# Libgdx change image scrollpane

Tags: libgdx

I have a table with some dots and the page number

```
        BitmapFont fuente = new BitmapFont(
                Gdx.files.internal("data/font/arial.fnt"), false);
        fuente.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        LabelStyle estiloLabel = new LabelStyle(fuente, Color.WHITE);
        numeroPagina = new Label("1",estiloLabel);
        numeroPagina.setAlignment(Align.center);
        numeroPagina.setFontScale(dPantalla.escalaLetra(0.6f));
        contenedor.row().fillX();
        contenedor.add(numeroPagina);

        paginador = new Image[numeroDePaginas];

        for(int i=0;i<numeroDePaginas;i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            paginador[i]=new Image(skin.getDrawable("pagina-selec"));
            else
            paginador[i]=new Image(skin.getDrawable("pagina-noselec"));

        }
        Table marcaPagina = new Table();
        //tablaEstrellas.defaults().pad(dPantalla.escalaDPI(5));
        for(Image a:paginador)
        {
            marcaPagina.add(a).width(dPantalla.escalaDPI(20)).height(dPantalla.escalaDPI(20)).pad(0,dPantalla.escalaDPI(15),dPantalla.escalaDPI(10),0);
        }
        contenedor.row();       
        contenedor.add(marcaPagina).fill();
```

When page change, i want change the page number and the dots. i have this code:

```
    if(aux>auxPagina)
    {
        paginador[0]=new Image(skin.getDrawable("pagina-noselec"));//Gray dot
        pagina++;
        paginador[1]= new Image(skin.getDrawable("pagina-selec"));//Yellow dot
    }
    else if(aux<auxPagina)
    {
        paginador[1]=new Image(skin.getDrawable("pagina-noselec"));//gray dot
        pagina--;
        paginador[0]=new Image(skin.getDrawable("pagina-selec"));//yellow dot
    }
    auxPagina=aux;
    numeroPagina.setText(""+pagina);
```

But the dots doesn't change.

First page:

[image]

Second page:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you are using `new Image` when switching page.
Instead you should store 2 `Drawable`s (`selected`, `notSelected`) and an `Image[]` for the pages/dots (`Image[] dots`). When you switch page you can do:

```
dots[currentPage].setDrawable(notSelected);
if (increment)      // Increment or decrement
    currentPage++;
else
    currentPage--;
 dots[currentPage].setDrawable(selected);
```

This should work. Note, that you need to check, if you can increment.
If you don't check that you will get an `Exception`.

Comment: Im glad, that i could help^^